# how to handle alert boxes in KARATE UI testing

Tags: karate

I have stared using Karate, as suggested by one of my client for our UI automation. it was some how going in good direction but as of now I am struggling to handle alert box on browser. I tried few things like switchFarme or input('body', Key.ENTER) but no success.
Can any one help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if `dialog()` helps: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#dialog

Else follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop/examples/ui-test

Comment: Thanks @Peter Thomas as of now dialog() is working for me.